# Regex on timestamp expression

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I am trying to check if a string matches the whole expression using the following code:

```
String expression = '^(19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])T(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]).([0-9]{3})Z?$';
String input ='2018-12-18T18:10:39.684';
system.debug(Pattern.compile(expression).matcher(input).matches());
```

Despite the `input` missing the `Z` at the end the match still returns true. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex concludes with `Z?`, which makes the `Z` optional. If you want to require the final `Z`, remove the `?` qualifier, which matches zero or one instance of the pattern.

If you do so, `matches()` will return `false`.

> 16:40:43:002 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|false